# Programatically save an eCharts4r chart

Tags: r, echarts4r

I can produce an eCharts4r gauge like

library(echarts4r)
library(magrittr)

```
CA_gauge <- e_charts() %>% 
  e_gauge(4.1, 
          "INCIDENCE", 
          min=0, 
          max=20,
          axisLine = list(
            linestyle = list(
              color=list(
                c(1.5/20, "green"),
                c(3/20, "yellow"),
                c(1, "red")
              )
            ))) %>% 
  e_title("CA")

print(CA_gauge)
```

But I haven't found a good way to save the output to a file so that I can use it later in a `gt` table.
The best I have been able to find is to add the "saveAsImage" to the output

```
e_charts() %>% 
      e_gauge(4.1, 
              "INCIDENCE", 
              min=0, 
              max=20,
              axisLine = list(
                linestyle = list(
                  color=list(
                    c(1.5/20, "green"),
                    c(3/20, "yellow"),
                    c(1, "red")
                  )
                ))) %>% 
        e_toolbox_feature(feature = c("saveAsImage"))
```

That adds a saveAs button in the upper right of the  RStudio viewer

[image]

But what I'd really like to do is just save the image (obviously without animation) in code to a tiff/jpg/png image file.

I tried using the standard devices like

```
tiff("CA_gauge.tif",sep=""), 
     res=600, compression = "lzw", height=5, width=15, units="in")
print(CA_gauge)
dev.off()
```

But that doesn't do it.  Any suggestions?